# Symfony form builder only works when fields are in a given order

Tags: forms, symfony

Here is a working code:

```
$formBuilder = $this->get('form.factory')->createBuilder('form', $scene);
$formBuilder->add('text', 'textarea', array('required' => false));
$formBuilder->add('duration', 'time', array('with_seconds' => true, 'input' => 'string'));
$formBuilder->add('submit', 'submit');
$form = $formBuilder->getForm();

$form->handleRequest($request);
```

When I switch the lines like this:

```
$formBuilder = $this->get('form.factory')->createBuilder('form', $scene);
$formBuilder->add('duration', 'time', array('with_seconds' => true, 'input' => 'string'));
$formBuilder->add('text', 'textarea', array('required' => false));
$formBuilder->add('submit', 'submit');
$form = $formBuilder->getForm();

$form->handleRequest($request);
```

it doesn't work anymore: the value of `duration` becomes `0` instead of something in the form of `00:00:00`.

I have no template to display them. In my twig page, I simple use `{{ form(form) }}`.

What's going on, there?

Comment: Please post the code for "When I switch the lines" so we can see if anything is wrong with how you switched them. It may also help to include the template where the form is being rendered (if there is one).

Comment: Show us the twig code where you display the form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copied your code and find anything wrong with it, you should be able to change the order of lines. But indirect solution would be leaving your code from the first example and manipulate order in the twig template:

```
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    {{ form_row(form.duration) }}
    {{ form_row(form.text) }}
    {{ form_rest(form) }}
```